# Powershell 5.1.16299.1146 Get-ADGroupMember An operations error occurred

Tags: powershell

I'm getting

> "An operations error occurred"

error when a group contains users from a different domain.

The same line in Powershell 5.1.14409.1018 works great.

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Server "MyDomain" -Identity "MyGroup" | ForEach-Object {$_.SamAccountName}
```

Is anyone else having a problem on version 5.1.16299.1146 with Get-ADGroupMember when the group contains users from a different domain?

> Get-ADGroupMember : An operations error occurred
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + Get-ADGroupMember  -Server "MyDomain" "MyGroup ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MyGroup:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember

Comment: Please update your question with a copy and paste of the exact error message. (Remember, we can't see your screen.)

Comment: I'm unable to replicate the issue - are you using correct domains/groups? - note i'm using PSVersion                      5.1.14393.2636

Comment: domains/groups are correct, the same line works great with 5.1.14409.1018

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-ADGroupMember` is notoriously bad at handling referral chasing for foreign security principals. You should be able to [do it manually](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/6pocuu/getadgroupmember_issue/) with `Get-ADGroup` and `Get-ADObject` though:

```bsh
Function Get-ADGroupMemberFix {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            ValueFromPipeline = $true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
            Position = 0
        )]
        [string[]]
        $Identity,

        [string]
        $Server
    )

    begin {
        $additionalArguments = @{}
        if($PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('Server')){
            $additionalArguments['Server'] = $Server
        }
    }

    process {
        foreach ($GroupIdentity in $Identity) {
            $Group = $null
            $Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity $GroupIdentity -Properties Member @additionalArguments
            if (-not $Group) {
                continue
            }
            Foreach ($Member in $Group.Member) {
                Get-ADObject $Member 
            }
        }
    }
}

Get-ADGroupMemberFix -Identity ''
```

(script above is a modified version of the script posted in the referenced reddit post by [/u/markekraus](https://www.reddit.com/user/markekraus))

You can add desired property name to the `Get-ADObject` call if needed

Comment: This is a good alternative, it does output a lot more information so hopefully, that's fine for OP - Edit - I just noticed, however, this doesn't appear to get `{$_.SamAccountName}`

Comment: I've never had an issue with Get-ADGroupMember until 5.1.16299.1146.
Looks like, that workaround only returns DistinguishedName, Name...I need to get the member SamAccountNames.

Comment: So pipe the member DNs to Get-ADUser and select sAMAccountName.

Comment: Or add `-Properties SamAccountName` to the Get-ADObject call - which might have been the indent of Mathias' last response line.