# Find groups in which the user is a member in another trusted domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

My Case is the following, I have a user in domain A who is members of groups in domain b, this domain is not a  member in the florest A but have a trusted relacion with domain A and i need obtain a list of groups this user is member on this domain

Try to do the search with the following command

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity 'user -ResourceContextServer 'domain2.com.br' and the command works fine in the domain controller but when i try on my machine returns error

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Erro de operações
No linha:1 caractere:1

- Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity 'XXX' -Resourc ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (XX:ADPrincipal) [Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership], ADExcept
  ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADPrincipalG
  roupMembership
  ```

I need to create a script to automate the creation of users and to my access control team an them cannot have access to the Domain Controller anyone know why this happen and what i can do?

Comment: You may need to specify the Domain Controller with the `-server` parameter, use the one where you had previous success. If this works then I suspect its because the server you auto connected to was not a Global Catalogue.

Comment: Yeah, any time you want to query another domain you need to specify a DC with that domain. Handy line I found, if you want to avoid having to hard code the individual DC name and reference the domain as a whole, you can add the following to find it dynamically, then use $dcServer in your command with -server :

$dcServer = Get-ADDomainController -discover -domain targetdomain.com -forcediscover | Select-Object -expandproperty hostname

Comment: I tried using -server on all DCs and I get the same error

Another thing, I was only able to execute the command successfully on the DCs of domain A only, on the DCs of domain B I get the same error.

Comment: Does the function posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58221736/powershell-5-1-16299-1146-get-adgroupmember-an-operations-error-occurred) help?

Comment: @jfrmilner Thanks for the answer but I couldn't understand how I could adjust it to my needs, in case it returns the list of members of a group I would need the list of groups of a user